# Allow others to view local IIS7 ASP web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a Visual Studio 2012 web application, and need to allow colleagues to view the current website by my IP address (while I would access it my localhost). It appears that hosting the site locally through IIS7 and allowing others to access it by my local IP the simplest method. After troubleshooting and experimenting for a day though, I still don't understand the relationship between an IIS7 site/website/application and Visual Studio web application, and the MSDN explanations are really hard to follow.

Basically, I'm trying to understand:

1) How to set up a IIS website and application (should the 'physical path' be the VS solution folder or deployment package .zip folder?, for example)

2) How to most simply deploy the web application (e.g. File System/ Web Deploy/ Web Package, etc.) and

3) The order to do all of this.

I'm running VS as administrator, my port 80 is open,  and have IIS7 set to use .NET v4, yet when I publish the selection using File System in VS2012 to my C drive, the resulting site gets a HTTP:500 error, with no source code underneath. (Also, before even publishing, setting the solution to use my Local IIS instead of IIS Express and previewing results in a blank page). If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to learn (or bother) with the details of setting it up, you can use a small utility like 'ngrok' that will allow others to view your website at 'localhost'.

Takes about 5 minutes to learn and get up and running (and its free).

https://ngrok.com/